# How to make button width equal to other button with the longer text

Tags: android, button

I have a few buttons with different text length.
I'd like to make all buttons equal to the button
with the longest text.
Their width is

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

So the buttons have different width.

I tried

```
      int width=button1.getWidth();
      button2.setWidth(width)
```

But they don't match each other. 
The width of button2 is different.
GetWidth gets I don't know what.
SetWidth sets pixels.

I don't want to use weight, because no guarantee that the text of button will
be as one line text. I don't want to set exact width of buttons, because there will be extra space on the left and on the right from button's text.

Any ideas please?
Thanks!

Comment: try to set specific width for both buttons for different density's screen try to use different `dimen` folder.

Comment: Is the pasted code within **oncreate()** or **oncreateview()**. If it's in oncreate then move it to oncrewreview, that will fix your problem

Comment: Sorry, not understood. As I wrote I'd like the width is equal for button with maximum text

Comment: Ranjith, yes, the code  within onCreate(). If I move it to onCreateView, will it fix the problem with different values for getWidth and setWidth? I have to research how to use this onCreateView...

Comment: Can't understand onCreateView. Looks like a headache, because I show a few pages inside of one Activity....

Comment: Could you make a JSFiddle please?

Comment: Ranjith, could you please write an example code of how I should use onCreateView(). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button is clickble" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Try this. Use weight in linear layout.

Comment: My buttons disappeared from the screen. Maybe width weights are not supported for vertical layout

Answer (score 0):

You are probably calling the `getWidth()` method too early, because if the UI hasn't finished loading and scaling yet, `getWidth()` will return an unwanted value.

Try logging the value of `getWidth()`. If it's zero, it's probably a duplicate of [getWidth() and getHeight() of View returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/android-get-width-returns-0)